How do I even out my faces/topology?
This is my first time modeling, so forgive me if this has an obvious solution. I need to subdivide my mesh to get more detail in preparation for using a displacement map. When I try subdividing the mesh, the face distribution is uneven. My edge flow is good. Do I just need to add edge loops to have even topology? Also, I have to consider that I'm using the bevel modifier, so I don't want the faces to be small enough that the bevel width starts overlapping surrounding edges.
